# FastAPI+beanie - Data conversion between input and output models

Tags: mongodb, fastapi, pydantic

I want to maintain some sync between input and output models with different datatypes for same fields across two models. To save some space in MongoDB I'm avoiding saving entire nested models by just storing just `ObjectId` on `Book` model/collection. My question is how to convert data on fly instead of extracting and modifying entire object via `beanie-odm`?

```
from beanie import Document, PydanticObjectId
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Author(Document):
    name: str
    email: str

class Book(Document):
    title: str
    author: PydanticObjectId

class BookOut(BaseModel):
    title: str
    author: Author | None = None
```

In above code `author` field of `BookOut` model expects entire author to be available on http response. But in MongoDB, only `Author's` `ObjectId` is saved via `Book` model. How to make this data conversion possible?

Comment: This is not a matter of _conversion_ because there is no data there to convert. You need to query the author data from you database first.

Comment: @Daniil Fajnberg Yes need to query. But how do it in seamless fashion such that I can write conversion logic Document or Base Model object?